# How to determine if 3 points are exactly collinear in Z^2

Tags: c

Another collinear-points question. This one's twist is, I'm using integer arithmetic, and I'm looking for *exact* collinearity, not a fuzzy epsilon-based test.

With inline assembly, I can get an exact answer: the x86 multiply instruction gives access to both the high and low parts of the product, both of which matter in calculating the cross product (**X** - **A**) **x** (**B** - **A**); I can simply OR the two halves together and test for zero. But I'm hoping there's a way to do it in C, that's:

1. Overflow-proof
2. Portable
3. Elegant

in roughly that order. And at the same time, a way to do it that is/does NOT:

1. involve casting to `double`
2. involve using a bigger integer type - assume that I'm already using the biggest integer type available for my coordinate component type
3. yield either false positives or false negatives.

I'm not concerned in this question about whether **X** is beyond the segment **AB**; that's just four uninteresting comparisons.

My nightmare scenario is that I'll have to break each coordinate component into two halves, and do long multiplication explicitly, just so I can keep track of all the high halves in the partial products. (And then having to do add-with-carry explicitly.)

Comment: Does the cross-product generalise to n dimensions?

Comment: Your title mentions Z^n, but the text of your question mentions the cross product, which I believe is only defined when n=3 (or n=2, by treating it as n=3 with z=0). Could you clarify whether you're looking for a general solution, or just an n=3 solution? I ask because, even though an n=2 or n=3 approach can easily be generalized to arbitrary dimensions (by checking for collinearity along overlapping two-or-three-element subsets of dimensions), it might be less elegant.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - [Yes, but it's an (`n-1`)-ary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Multilinear_algebra).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity, fixed title to Z^2 (embedded in a Z^3 world)

Comment: In Z^2, I think this problem is equivalent to "how do I determine if two rational numbers are equivalent?".

Comment: Hmmmm....any method involving vector arithmetic of any kind (dot products, cross products, parameterizing a line in 3-D space) is going to involve subtracting the coordinates of one point from the respective coordinates of another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some comparisons and simple checks, you can get 2 couple of positive numbers `(x1,y1)`, `(x2,y2)`, that you want to check if `x1*y2==x2*y1`.

You can use the Euclidean algorithm to find the GCD of `x1` and `y1`, and divide them both by the GCM. Do the same thing for `(x2,y2)`. If you got the same couple in both cases, then both vectors have the same direction.

Comment: But what if all the numbers are co-prime and large?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Then the GCD is 1, and `x1*y2==x2*y1` iff `x1==x2 && y1==y2`

Comment: Oh, I see what you're getting at.

Comment: +1: I have a feeling that this achieves all the OP's goals.  However, it will almost certainly be less computationally efficient than just emulating long multiplication (GCD typically involves modulo arithmetic).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: The Euclidean algorithm doesn't involve any modulo arithmetic, just comparison and subtraction. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm.

Comment: @ruakh: Yeah, I guess it depends which implementation you choose.  But you trade a modulo operation for a repeated subtract; neither of those is cheap.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: It's probably not as efficient as emulating long multiplication, but efficiency wasn't one of the OP's conditions. (Ceteris paribus, I suppose a more-efficient algorithm is more elegant than a less-efficient one, but of course, ceteris is never really paribus. I think asaelr's solution is elegant.)

Comment: Ooh, the only caveat here is that calculating `x1`, `y1`, etc. may risk overflow (i.e. the initial subtractions).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I suggest to sort the points by the X values, and check the orders of the Y values. Then, you can put the differences in an `unsigned`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Oh, I now belatedly get what you mean about modulo arithmetic: if, at any given step, one of the numbers is many times bigger than the other, it would be faster to compute `a % b` than `a - b - b . . . - b`. I don't know how I missed that. :-P

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm going to settle with something that amounts to using Euclid's method, albeit indirectly: I'm not interested in the gcd so much as the quotient x1*y2/gcd. I wrote about it at http://bpj-code.blogspot.com/2012/02/tricking-gcc-into-tco.html - please give me a yell if I goofed the implementation!

Answer (score 0):

If three points (a, b, c) are exactly colinear then the following identity holds:

```
c = a + (a - b) * scalar
```

i.e.:

```
c - a = scalar * (a - b)
```

So take the first component of `(c-a)`, divide it by the first component of `(a-b)`, save that value. Then repeat for each subsequent component, and if any of them differ, the points are not colinear.

If you want to avoid completely using floating point division (which would be the easiest way to do it), then you'll have to store the ratio, and compare that instead.

Comment: That fails the "avoid casting to double" requirement.  If you use rationals instead of doubles, there may be an overflow issue.

Comment: That's logically equivalent to what I was about to answer, but the problem is that you could easily end up with floats when dividing one component by another, and it sounds like the OP wants to avoid floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @Osi, Jack; see edit. Also, checking ratios are the same without reducing to the most basic form might be quite easy with integer division.

Comment: I want to avoid floating point arithmetic because I have no guarantee that `double` has any more precision than `int`. `double` could be a 52-bit-mantissa type, whilst `int` could be a 64-bit integer. So indeed, floating point division is out.

Comment: @BerndJendrissek That isn't necessarily true. You could get away with fewer bits of precision in your double than your int if you could place some constraint on the ratio of (a-b):(c-a), in any case, see note about comparing ratios: you can compare ratios by multiplying up to the largest of the numerators that you're comparing, no floating point involved.