# How to correctly compare 2 doubles?

Tags: c, double, comparison

I'm doing calculations with triangles. But I need to know if three given points aren't on the same line. To do that, I'm calculating an area of the triangle

> area=(Ax* (By-Cy) + Bx* (Cy-Ay) + Cx* (Ay-By));

If the area equals zero, then all three points are colinear.
But the problem is, that it never really equals zero since doubles and floats are very inaccurate, so

```
if(area==0){
 printf("It's not a triangle");   
 }
```

won't work. How is the correct way of overcoming this problem?

Comment: You need to show us the code. As an aside, and not thinking about comparing doubles,  why don't you use the equation of the straight line to check if the points don't lie on the same line? You should have the slope.

Comment: In any event, as is usually the case with numerical methods, you still need to set a tolerance for what you'd consider close enough to zero. Say, 0.00000001 or some such, depending on your particular situation.

Comment: Essential reading: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/

Comment: @TanoFotang: They do not need to show us the code. Showing us the code is for questions asking why certain code is not working. It is not needed for questions seeking a method for doing something. Regarding your suggestion of using the equation for a straight line, should not the mathematics be equivalent? A (potentially degenerate) triangle formed from the points will have zero area if and only if the distance of the third point fro a line formed by the first two is non-zero. Do you think the latter calculation leads to an expression more suitable to accurate evaluation?

Comment: Do you know the points you have in the `float` or `double` values are exact in the first place? If they are not, it is impossible to determine with certainty whether or not they are exactly on a line, regardless of what arithmetic is used. Can you accept a false positive (a report the points are on a line when they are not exactly) or a false negative (a report the points are not on a line when they are exactly) at all, or must the answers always be exactly correct?

Comment: I expect a solution is possible with a reasonable amount of work. C’s `fma` can be used to get exact products for the various individual terms such as `Ax*By`, in two floating-point objects per term (one for the normal result of `Ax*By` and one for the residue of rounding, extracted via `fma(Ax*By, -Ax, By)`). Then the six terms can be exactly added with some extended-precision work.

Comment: Another approach is that the floating-point format constrains the possibilities. Point C cannot be an arbitrary point on AB; it must have coordinates that are exactly floating-point values. Some number theory might help reduce the problem. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474453/how-to-determine-if-3-points-are-exactly-collinear-in-z2) poses the same problem (colinear detection) for integers, and that might be useful for this approach.

Comment: @EricPostpischil (wow isn't that a Czech name? :D) It's a school project. A have to scan for 2x 3 points from the user and then determine if it's possible to make a triangle out of those points and if those triangles are the same/same area/or which is bigger. They are giving extra small or extra large numbers into the program so they test if it's foolproof

Comment: Doubles are not "very" inaccurate. They are normally  quite accurate, although certain types of computation can magnify error terms (subtracting similar numbers, for example). Floats are not very accurate and normally should not be used for analytic computation, although they are often fine for graphucs, which only has to be pixel accurate. Even so, they are not "very inaccurate". They are within one in a million.

Comment: Given this is a school project, it is unlikely they want an exact test for colinearity, unless the class specifically covers floating-point arithmetic. (More than just an introduction and general use; getting this answer exactly correct is not a introductory level technique.) So it would be a bit surprising if the test cases relied on working around floating-point limitations here. Do you have any test cases that fail? (Nonetheless, solving the problem exactly is interesting and could be a good Stack Overflow Q&A.)

Comment: Yes, my surname comes from a Czech word for a busy or active person.

Comment: Well, this is kind of an extra thing to do, but it keeps bothering me how to do it. We have some tolerance approved though. I have about 6 sample data with an expected output and I just can't get them to work all at once.

Comment: Show the data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets us clear some causally understandings and dig deeper.

**Wrong formula for area**

The area is 1/2 of OP's formula, yet that does not make a different when comparing to 0.0.

```
// area=(Ax* (By-Cy) + Bx* (Cy-Ay) + Cx* (Ay-By));
area=(Ax* (By-Cy) + Bx* (Cy-Ay) + Cx* (Ay-By))/2;
```

**Inaccuracy**

"since doubles and floats are very inaccurate" is itself inaccurate.  All finite FP values are *exact*, just like integers.  It is when comparing their operations against mathematical divide, they get the mis-nomer of "inaccurate".  Like integer divide, FP divide and other basic FP math OPs, they are defined differently than math operations.  7/3 and 7.0/3.0 both do not result in the mathematical 2<sup>1</sup>/<sub>3</sub>, but a different value.  When C employs an IEEE math model, that "quotient" is not approximate, but exact.

**Comparing how many?**

"compare 2 doubles" misleads as effectively it a complicated compare of 6 `double` that code needs to perform.

---

**Review of the test formula**

`Ax* (By-Cy) + Bx* (Cy-Ay) + Cx* (Ay-By)` with `double` operands will behave without rounding as long as the sub-steps do not round.  In *general*, this is not possible.  The work-arounds are

1. Use higher precision

Perform the test using `long double`.  This does not eliminate the issue, just makes it smaller/less likely.  Note `long double` is not required to have higher precision.

2. Employ some sort of *epsilon*

A naive approach takes the result |computed area| and compares against an *epsilon*.  Absolute areas below that are considered "zero".  This does not scale well as the *epsilon* really depends on the magnitude of operands relative to the area. A *relative* epsilon is needed.  Suggest `fmax(|ax|,|bx|,|cx|) * fmax(|ay|,|by|,|cy|) * DBL_EPSILON`.  This is only a first order approximation.

3. Look for sign change

The area formula is a *signed* area.  Effectively reversing the order of a,b,c inverts the sign of the area.  Should a small perturbation of any one of the 8 operands by `operand_new=operand*(1 +/- DBL_EPSILON)`result in an area sign change, the area can be assessed "close enough to zero".

4. Re-order the formula.

It is the subtraction of distant values values that kill  precision.  Exchanging `x`s with `y`s may help in the inner term subtractions.  Re-ordering subtraction of the 3 products can help.

A better re-ordering can take the form of forming the 6 products: Ax*By, -Ax*Cy, Bx*Cy, -Bx*Ay, Cx*Ay, -Cx*By and then sum those.

Both of these benefit by using [Kahan summation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6699451/2410359), perhaps taking advantage of [`fma()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fma).

---

For me, I'd explore #4b or #3.  Had OP posted an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), sample data and expected sample results, true code could be had.  Lacking that, consider these starting ideas for a fuzzy problem.

Answer (score -1):

You figure out: How much could the rounding errors be? If you use double precision, and the result of a single operation is x, then the rounding error can be up to abs (x) / 2^52. (If you don't use double then use double. )

You do this and find the rounding error in By-Cy, Cy-Ay, Ay-By. These three errors are multiplied by Ax, Bx and Cx. The three products have their own rounding error. Then you have an error adding the first two products, then adding the third product. You add up all these errors and get a maximum total error e.

So if the area is less than e, then you can assume they are on a straight line.

To improve on this: If Ax, Bx, Cx are all positive (say 100, 101, 102.5), then you calculate the average and subtract from Ax, Bx and Cx. That makes your numbers smaller and the rounding errors smaller.

Comment: There are a number of errors in this. To start, the design of accepting as zero a non-zero result if it is close enough is defective, as it allows results that **ought** to be small non-zero values to be accepted as zero. The question asks for a **correct** way of overcoming the accuracy problem, which means getting both true zero and true non-zero results correct.

Comment: The statement that the rounding error can be up to |x|/2^52 is wrong on two points. First, in the usual default round-to-nearest-ties-to-even mode, the maximum error for normal numbers is 1/2 ULP. With 53-bit significands, the ULP is 2^−52 of the leading bit, so 1/2 ULP is 2^−53, not 2^−52. Additionally, for subnormal numbers, the relative error can be much greater.

Comment: Although the answer states a bound on the rounding error for a single operation, it does not follow through to explain rounding errors for compound operations. Such errors quickly become complicated, as the error in each operation can be bound relative to that operation’s result (while it remains within the range of the format), but then the error takes part of subsequent operations and complicates them. In fairly simple expressions, it may be feasible to express bounds by permitting additional slack in them, but this opens up more possibility of false positives.

Comment: Subtracting the average is not a bad idea, and Sterbenz’ lemma tells us the differences will be exact if the average is within ½ of a value it is subtracted from, or vice-versa, but, if it is not, the subtraction has its own rounding error, which must be considered.

Answer (score -2):

I would try something like this:

`#include <float.h>
    ...
    if ( (area < FLT_EPSILON) && (area > -FLT_EPSILON) )
    {
        printf("It's not a triangle"); 
    }`

Comment: There are **many** triangles with areas smaller than `FLT_EPSILON` that this code would falsely report are not triangles. Conversely, there are colinear points whose magnitudes are so large that the naîve calculation of the area of a triangle will result in an erroneous result larger than `FLT_EPSILON`, causing this code to falsely report them as triangles.